# Unknown index keyword \indexentry, empty .ilg file

Tags: indexing, makeindex

I am trying to create multiple indices with splitidx (the problem occurred also with multind and amsmidx), but when I run makeindex, it rejects all my entries and i get this message in the .ilg logfile: "Unknown index keyword \indexentry[Hal].!!" from the MWE below, same for [Alka].

```
\documentclass[a4paper, headsepline, footsepline, tablecaptionabove, 12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{splitidx}
\makeindex
\newindex[As]{Hal}
\newindex[Bs]{Alka}
\begin{document}

\section{A}
Eintrag A\sindex[Hal]{A}
\newpage

\section{B}
Eintrag B\sindex[Alka]{B}

\newpage
\printindex*


\end{document}
```

my index file looks like this:

```
\indexentry[Hal]{A}{1}
\indexentry[Alka]{B}{2}
```

I never used indices before, so maybe I am doing something basic very wrong. I am using Texmaker for the record, with or without admin privileges doesnt matter.

Comment: You need to run the program `splitindex`, rather than `makeindex`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the package `splitidx` is involved, the production of the actual indices has to performed by `splitindex` rather than `makeindex` (that's internally called by `splitindex` with appropriate parameters).

So the workflow is

```
pdflatex filename
splitindex filename
pdflatex filename
```